# Pandas groupby for multiple values in a column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame similar to the following

```
+----------------+-------+
| class          | year  |
+----------------+-------+
| ['A', 'B']     | 2001  |
| ['A']          | 2002  |
| ['B']          | 2001  |
| ['A', 'B', 'C']| 2003  |
| ['B', 'C']     | 2001  |
| ['C']          | 2003  |
+----------------+-------+
```

I want to create a data frame using this so that the resulting table shows the count of each category in class per yer.

```
+-----+----+----+----+
|year | A  | B  | C  |
+-----+----+----+----+
|2001 | 1  | 3  | 1  |
|2002 | 1  | 0  | 0  |
|2003 | 1  | 1  | 2  |
+-----+----+----+----+
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-to-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
s=unnesting(df,['class'])
```

Then, we do `crosstab`

```
pd.crosstab(s['year'],s['class'])
```

Method from `sklearn`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['class']),columns=mlb.classes_, index=df.year).sum(level=0)
Out[293]: 
      A  B  C
year         
2001  2  2  1
2002  1  1  1
2003  0  1  1
```

---

Method of `get_dummies`

```
df.set_index('year')['class'].apply(','.join).str.get_dummies(sep=',').sum(level=0)
Out[297]: 
      A  B  C
year         
2001  2  2  1
2002  1  1  1
2003  0  1  1
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```

Comment: What if class column contains a list of strings, instead of list of characters. For instance ['above_average', 'average', 'below_average']. MultiLabelBinarizer doesn't work in this case.

Comment: @ksaliya I think all above method still work for that case

Comment: MultiLabelBinarizer created columns per each character in the the category in the data set I've tested. But, your answer was extremely helpful. Thank you.